# How do I convert a NSString into a std::string?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I have an `NSString` object and want to convert it into a `std::string`.

How do I do this in Objective-C++?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3552195/918764

Comment: @rvalue not a duplicate -- just the opposite conversion.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
NSString *foo = @"Foo";
std::string bar = std::string([foo UTF8String]);
```

Edit: After a few years, let me expand on this answer. As rightfully pointed out, you'll most likely want to use `cStringUsingEncoding:` with `NSASCIIStringEncoding` if you are going to end up using `std::string`. You can use UTF-8 with normal `std::strings`, but keep in mind that those operate on bytes and not on characters or even graphemes. For a good "getting started", check out this [question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011082/c-stdstring-and-utf-8).

Also note, if you have a string that can't be represented as ASCII but you still want it in an `std::string` and you don't want non-ASCII characters in there, you can use `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` to get an `NSData` representation of the string with lossy encoded ASCII content, and then throw that at your `std::string`

Comment: Careful of encoding. While UTF-8 is generally a good choice, if the API you're working with expects, say, pure ASCII or the system codepage, you'll have to use `-cStringUsingEncoding:` instead. :)

Comment: This is a memory leak if you don't delete it, the returned pointer is not an Objective-C reference counted object. In general you should avoid using operator new for std::string.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer and definitely not the first thing to consider when doing that conversion.

Comment: @JBL After only 4 years and a few weeks I went around to expand my answer. I hope it's more acceptable now.

Comment: @JustSid I should have precised my opinion, but the other issue is the use of a pointer by default. As a matter of fact, a coworker with an ObjC background, with no C++ knowledge used that, without deleting, ending up in a memory leak. And more generally; wild `new`s are frowned upon, and a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` should be preferred.

Comment: @JBL Whoa, thanks for pointing that out. The original answer used a pointer, a year ago that was changed to a non pointer answer but apparently it was rolled back. I'll edit the pointer out again, sorry. On the upside, I finally have proof that I'm providing people with bad advice on SO that they blindly copy and paste, I feel honoured :p

Comment: @JustSid That's exactly one of the reason for why I wanted to point this out: as some people just come and blindly copy paste, that's a big incitement to make the answers as correct as possible... :P

Answer (score 50):

As Ynau's suggested in the comment, in a general case it would be better to keep everything on the stack instead of heap (using `new` creates the string on the heap), hence (assuming UTF8 encoding):

```
NSString *foo = @"Foo";
std::string bar([foo UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 13):

As noted on [philjordan.eu](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++) it could also be that the NSString is `nil`. In such a case the cast should be done like this:

> // NOTE: if foo is nil this will produce an empty C++ string
>
> // instead of dereferencing the NULL pointer from UTF8String.

This would lead you to such a conversion:

```
NSString *foo = @"Foo";
std::string bar = std::string([foo UTF8String], [foo lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: This is tremendously useful. Worrying to see almost everyone is overlooking it.  Y'all gona crash on NIL.

Comment: This is definitely a much better answer. Btw, if you already have a string there's no need to invoke one more constructor and destructor for std::string. Just do: `strYouHave.assign([foo UTF8String], [foo lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])`