# Converting NSString to std::string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, objective-c++, stdstring

I try to pass a NSString to a C++ function, but I only get the first letter. Here is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <string>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {
    NSString* objcString=@"test";
    std::string cppString([objcString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]);
    NSLog(@"%@, %s",objcString, cppString.c_str()
          );

}
return 0;
}
```

It gives me:

```
2013-03-05 10:22:15.362 TEST[1136:353] test, t
```

Thank for your time, have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding is wrong. `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` returns an UTF-16 string. The characters "t, e, s, t" fit in one byte - so in UTF-16, they're represented by a non-zero byte and a zero byte. The zero tells `NSLog()` that it's the end of the string. Use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead.

Comment: But so how can I do if I want to use exotic character as 'é'?

Comment: @user1987722 The same. UTF-8 ain't ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
std::string cppString([objcString UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it ubiquitously in my code with `NSUTF8Encoding` instead that `NSUnicodeEncoding`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might help you: [How do I convert a NSString into a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001677/how-do-i-convert-a-nsstring-into-a-stdstring)

For integrity:

```
NSString *foo = @"Foo";
std::string *bar = new std::string([foo UTF8String]);
```