# Get unichar * from a C++ std::string& to create a nonnull NSString in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsstring, objective-c++, stdstring

I have some Objective-C++ that wraps an existing C++ library. The C++ library occasionally gives me `std::string&` parameters that I want to convert into `nonnull` `NSString`s. Almost all of the `NSString` initializers return `nullable NSString`s except: `-initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:` and `-initWithCharacters:length:`. However, both of those require `unichar *`, but `std::string.c_str()` returns `char *`.

How can I get a `unichar *` from a C++ `std::string` so that I can create an `NSString * _Nonnull` ?

**Not a duplicate**

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552195/9636) simply want to convert from `std::string` to `NSString`. I want to know if it's possible to do so without producing a `null` `NSString *`, possibly by calling methods on `std::string` to get `unichar *`. [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) looks promising, but I'm not a C++ developer, so I don't know how to get started with that yet.

**Possible solution**

After researching further, I learned that `std::string` is just a `std::basic_string<char>`, and it seems like you can define your own `std::basic_string`s. I found a [similar example that converts to `std::wstring`](http://blog.mijalko.com/2008/06/convert-stdstring-to-stdwstring.html):

```
// std::string -> std::wstring
std::string s("string");
std::wstring ws;
ws.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

So I adapted it to `std::basic_string<unichar>`, and it compiles fine:

```
void Foo(const std::string& bar) {
  std::basic_string<unichar> barUnichar;
  barUnichar.assign(bar.begin(),
                    bar.end());
  NSString * _Nonnull barNSString = 
  [NSString stringWithCharacters:barUnichar.c_str() 
                          length:barUnichar.length()];
  NSLog(@"bar: %@", bar);
}
```

I don't mind that converting from `std::string` to `std::basic_string<unichar>` performs a needless copy, and I imagine I can change the above code to use `-[NSString initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:]` once I learn more about C++ memory ownership rules.

**Possible solution is no good**

[Joe Groff says on twitter](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/834987891541471232):

> That's going to do a byte-by-byte mapping. It may work for ASCII but
>   will give you garbage for any Unicode.

Comment: CRD's answer and comment are correct. An `NSString * _Nonnull` isn't really a thing. The nullability annotations don't exist after compilation. It's just an indication that the method can fail to produce a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try again, see if it helps you. You have edited the question in response to the suggestion it is a duplicate and added:

> [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552195/9636) simply want to convert from `std::string` to `NSString`. I want to know if it's possible to do so without producing a `null` `NSString *`...

**The direct answer: No**

The reason is straightforward: The Objective-C library cannot assume that any pointer passed to it references a validly encoded C string, even if that pointer is typed `std::string`.

Now you may be very confident that your C++ code will never pass you an invalidly encoded string – and it can be argued that confidence is reasonable (but then it is C++ after all ;-)) – and so believe the null result will never happen, but that does not change the fact that the Objective-C library cannot assume it won't.

**The DIY answer: Yes**

Trying to avoid the null, e.g. by trying to convert the `std::string` into a `unichar *` etc. as you have considered, just avoids the issue - some piece of code somewhere has to deal with checking the encoding or risk returning an invalidly encoded `NSString`.

While it might be possible to do this it will both be more involved, and may leave you not knowing what is returned for invalid encodings, compared to the DIY approach: just deal with the null return yourself at source and replace it by something else. For example:

```
std::string someCstring;

NSString *convertedString = @(someCstring.c_str()) ?: @"ERROR: C string is invalid UTF8";
```

Here `convertedString` will never be `nil`.

(If your C string is not UTF8 you will need to use another `NSString` initialiser which takes an encoding.)

HTH

Comment: It seems like I found a possible solution (I've edited my question). What do you think?